# Change position of legend in Carto Builder

Tags: carto

I just opened an old map of mine that I had made in CartoDB Editor in the new Carto Builder. Without doing anything to the new map, I see that the legend has been moved from the lower right-hand corner to the upper left-hand corner of the map and is now covering the map description text. I am still a noob at CSS/HTML, so I'm not sure how to move my legend back to the lower right-hand corner, and I'm not finding anything online that is working. A while back I edited the legend labels, using the following HTML code. I'm assuming the legend position has to be included in this HTML code as well? Maybe as a new div class?

```
<div class='cartodb-legend category'>   
<ul>

  <li>
        <div class="bullet" style="background: #f2b2db"></div> Newark (EWR) Departures
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="bullet" style="background: #e05fab"></div> Newark (EWR) Arrivals
    </li>  
    <li>
        <div class="bullet" style="background: #fff7af"></div> LaGuardia (LGA) Departures
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="bullet" style="background: #edab38"></div> LaGuardia (LGA) Arrivals
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="bullet" style="background: #5ca2d1"></div> Kennedy (JFK) Departures
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="bullet" style="background: #2e5387"></div> Kennedy (JFK) Arrivals
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Here's my map for reference: [Flights over Queens!](https://kgrady.carto.com/builder/63cc8fe2-6f99-11e4-ab18-0e018d66dc29/embed?state=%7B%22map%22%3A%7B%22ne%22%3A%5B38.64261790634527%2C-80.5078125%5D%2C%22sw%22%3A%5B42.69051116998238%2C-67.5%5D%7D%7D)
(Which clearly has way more wrong with it now than just the legend. I'm assuming this is all from switching over to Builder? Oy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legend position in CARTO Builder can't be changed. If the map was created in CARTO Editor and you have opened in CARTO Builder, CARTO has transformed the configuration of the map to CARTO Builder. So the problems that you are experiencing might be caused by the transformation of the map to CARTO Builder configuration.

Comment: Oof. Seems like a pretty big design flaw. Was there a way I could have avoided messing up my map so that I don't mess up any others? And I guess the solution then is to create a new map in Builder from scratch, huh?

Comment: Once the map has been opened with the Builder, yo can't change its configuration. When you open a map created in the Editor with the new Builder, if the map has elements that are only available in the Editor, CARTO warns you before opening the map so you can go back to the map dahsboard.

Comment: It definitely gave me a message, but I just assumed a) that I had to open it in Builder to edit it (and I had to edit it) and that b) it wouldn't cause such major changes to take place. I must have misunderstood the message or maybe it wasn't clear enough. So is the only way to fix it to make a new one in Builder?

Comment: Also, if I make a new one in Builder, I would then have control over the (new) legend placement via HTML, right? I can't imagine Carto forces everyone to place a legend in the top left corner of all their maps...